# PrimeFaces DataTable rowSelect cannot check checkbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I was trying to "link" `<p:ajax event="rowSelect">` and `<p:ajax event="rowUnselect">` with `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` so when datatable row is selected, the checkbox would check together and when checkbox is checked, datatable row is selected too.

Problem for now: I can save the state of the checkbox when going to another pagination page but I need to check checkbox then select row then only it will save the state. If I tried to check only checkbox and go to other pagination page, it won't save the state when I come back to the pagination page but if I select row and go to other pagination page, it would save the state. If I select row and check checkbox and go to another pagination page, it won't save the state too. Any idea how to check checkbox and select row when either 1 is clicked and can save state if go to another pagination page?

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{machine.sub}" var="subDir" 
                 id="fileDirectories" rowClasses="row1-whitebg,row2-bluebg" 
                 selectionMode="multiple" selectionPageOnly="false" 
                 rowKey="#{subDir.directory.path}" headerClass="title-column" 
                 rowIndexVar="idx" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50" paginator="true" 
                 paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" 
                 paginatorTemplate="#{WebConstant.PAGINATOR_TEMPLATE}">
    
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{machine.selectedRow}"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{machine.unSelectedRow}"/>
        
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg['machine_download']}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupChkSelect">
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkSelect" value="#{subDir.selected}"
                                                 rendered="#{subDir.directory.file}">
                            <c:if test="#{machineLogExplorerPage.checkButton()}">
                                <f:attribute name="checked" value="checked"/>
                            </c:if>
                        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Java code

```
private boolean checked;

  public void selectedRow() {
    checked = true;
  }

  public void unSelectedRow() {
    checked = false;
  }

  public boolean checkButton() {
    return checked;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement the checkbox yourself. Just add a selection column like:

```html
<p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

To keep track of what is selected use:

```html
<p:dataTable selectionMode="multiple"
             selection="#{bean.listOfSelectedItems}"
             ...>
```

See:

- https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/datatable?id=multiple-selection-with-checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually tried this method before but unfortunately when I tried to put like this `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" value="#{subDir.selected}" />`, it seems like the value is not "enter" in my Java.

Comment: That's not how to keep track of what is selected. See update.

Comment: Ahh finally understand what to do after few try. Thank you so much, was struggling this part for so long. Thank you! Appreciate your help so much!